# Logstash Index error : [logstash-*] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new for ELK. 
I am using :
-   elasticsearch-2.1.0
-   logstash-2.1.1
-   kibana-4.3.0-windows
I tried to configure ELK to monitoring my application logs and I followed different tutorials and different logstash configuration, but I am getting this error when I switch on kibana, and it send the request to the elasticsearch. :

```
[logstash-*] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]
```

This is my logstash config:

```
input {
   file {
       path => "/var/logs/*.log"
       type => "syslog"
        }
      } 
filter {
       grok {match => [ "message", "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" ] }
} 
output {
      elasticsearch { hosts => localhost }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I tried to deleted all folder and re-install it and follow  this tutorial step by step: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html

But I didn't received any kind of index, and I got again the `index Error` from `kibana` to `elasticsearch`

Any helps ?

Regards
debug Logs : 
`

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\LOGS\logstash-2.1.1\bin>logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --debug
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
←[36mReading config file {:config_file=>"C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/bin/first-pipeline.conf", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby
/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"325", :method=>"local_config"}←[0m
←[36mCompiled pipeline code:
        @inputs = []
        @filters = []
        @outputs = []
        @periodic_flushers = []
        @shutdown_flushers = []
        @input_file_1 = plugin("input", "file", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "path" => ("/var/logs/logstash-tutorial-dataset") }, { "start_position" => ("beginning") }))
        @inputs << @input_file_1
        @filter_grok_2 = plugin("filter", "grok", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "match" => {("message") => ("%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}")} }))
        @filters << @filter_grok_2
            @filter_grok_2_flush = lambda do |options, &block|
              @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("Flushing", :plugin => @filter_grok_2)
              events = @filter_grok_2.flush(options)
              return if events.nil? || events.empty?
              @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("Flushing", :plugin => @filter_grok_2, :events => events)
                          events = @filter_geoip_3.multi_filter(events)
              events.each{|e| block.call(e)}
            end
            if @filter_grok_2.respond_to?(:flush)
              @periodic_flushers << @filter_grok_2_flush if @filter_grok_2.periodic_flush
              @shutdown_flushers << @filter_grok_2_flush
            end
          @filter_geoip_3 = plugin("filter", "geoip", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "source" => ("clientip") }))
          @filters << @filter_geoip_3
            @filter_geoip_3_flush = lambda do |options, &block|
              @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("Flushing", :plugin => @filter_geoip_3)
              events = @filter_geoip_3.flush(options)
              return if events.nil? || events.empty?
              @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("Flushing", :plugin => @filter_geoip_3, :events => events)
              events.each{|e| block.call(e)}
            end
            if @filter_geoip_3.respond_to?(:flush)
              @periodic_flushers << @filter_geoip_3_flush if @filter_geoip_3.periodic_flush
              @shutdown_flushers << @filter_geoip_3_flush
            end
          @output_elasticsearch_4 = plugin("output", "elasticsearch", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "hosts" => [("localhost")] }))
          @outputs << @output_elasticsearch_4
  def filter_func(event)
    events = [event]
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("filter received", :event => event.to_hash)
              events = @filter_grok_2.multi_filter(events)
              events = @filter_geoip_3.multi_filter(events)
    events
  end
  def output_func(event)
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("output received", :event => event.to_hash)
    @output_elasticsearch_4.handle(event)
  end {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"38", :method=>"initialize"}←[0m
←[36mPlugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"input", :name=>"file", :path=>"logstash/inputs/file", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}←[0m
[...]
Logstash startup completed
←[32mFlushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x75375e77@stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x61b12c0>, @last_flush=2015-12-29 15:45:27 +0000, @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x7008acbf run>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x4985690f>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x3c9b0727@C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:55>, @flush_interval=1, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0x65f2b086 @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0x202361b4>, @data={}, @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x72e380e7 @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0x65f2b086 ...>, @metrics={}, @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x3623f89e>>, @subscribers={12592=>#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x316290ee @lock=#<Mutex:0x3e191296>, @io=#<IO:fd 1>>}, @level=:debug>, @buffer=[], @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x601355b3>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:info, :file=>"/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsear
ch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}←[0m
←[36m_globbed_files: /var/logs/logstash-tutorial-dataset: glob is: ["/var/logs/logstash-tutorial-dataset"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/Users/xxx/Desktop/LOGS/logstash-2.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.6.7/lib/filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"190", :method=>"_globbed_files"}←[0m`
```

elasticsearch.log :

```
[2015-12-29 15:15:01,702][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: syscall filtering not supported for OS: 'Windows 8.1'
[2015-12-29 15:15:01,879][INFO ][node                     ] [Blue Marvel] version[2.1.1], pid[10152], build[40e2c53/2015-12-15T13:05:55Z]
[2015-12-29 15:15:01,880][INFO ][node                     ] [Blue Marvel] initializing ...
[2015-12-29 15:15:01,923][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Blue Marvel] loaded [], sites []
[2015-12-29 15:15:01,941][INFO ][env                      ] [Blue Marvel] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OS (C:)]], net usable_space [242.8gb], net total_space [458.4gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2015-12-29 15:15:03,135][INFO ][node                     ] [Blue Marvel] initialized
[2015-12-29 15:15:03,135][INFO ][node                     ] [Blue Marvel] starting ...
[2015-12-29 15:15:03,249][INFO ][transport                ] [Blue Marvel] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2015-12-29 15:15:03,255][INFO ][discovery                ] [Blue Marvel] elasticsearch/3DpYKTroSke4ruP21QefmA
[2015-12-29 15:15:07,287][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Blue Marvel] new_master {Blue Marvel}{3DpYKTroSke4ruP21QefmA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2015-12-29 15:15:07,377][INFO ][http                     ] [Blue Marvel] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2015-12-29 15:15:07,382][INFO ][node                     ] [Blue Marvel] started
[2015-12-29 15:15:07,399][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Blue Marvel] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2015-12-29 16:33:00,715][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /logstash-$DATE/_search Params: {index=logstash-$DATE, q=response=200}
[logstash-$DATE] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.resolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:566)
```

Comment: Can you try to run logstash with the `--debug` command line switch and update your question with the output you're getting?

Comment: I tried but logstash is logging a plenty of logs. what should I show ?

Comment: That's the idea ;-) Just want to see what is flowing where, or whether errors are flying under the radar.

Comment: could I save it in to the file?

Comment: You don't need to store the full thing, just when logstash starts up and begins consuming your logs. Nothing more. About 200 lines, you can paste them in your question without any problems.

Comment: Also, if elasticsearch is having trouble creating the index, it might log something in its logs.

Comment: Switch your outputs around in the Logstash configuration. If you never see anything displayed on the console, then nothing is going to be sent to Elasticsearch.

Comment: I tried to follow step by step this tutorial : `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html` but same error.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, it seems that you've not provided port no in logstash output config file. Generally the port used is **9200** (default) for elasticsearch (as instructed by most of the tutorials outh there). Try changing logstash config - output part to follows and let me know if it works:

```
output {
      elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I added in my output your example, but still doesn't work. And here `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices` I have only this : `yellow open .kibana 1 1 1 0 3.1kb 3.1kb`

Comment: I tried the same steps in Ubuntu and it is working immediately.

Thank you for your time

Comment: **Errata codices**:
I tried the same steps in Ubuntu and it was working. 
Than I deleted the index in elasticsearch with : 
`curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.12.30/`
and try to recreate it with a different config file and logstash wasn't sent the new index to the elasticsearch.
someone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem adding this:
`input {
     file {
     path => "/path/to/logstash-tutorial.log"
      start_position => beginning`
      **`sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`**
    `}
  }`

now logstash is sending the index to elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

This issue will fix with below logstash config file change.

```
 input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/logfile.log"
        start_position => beginning 
    }
}

filter {

}


output {
      elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"    
                    }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```